# Where can I find a brick?

Tags: tinker-island

My camp is stuck at 8,200 capacity for resources, and I need a brick in order to upgrade to "Storage 14" that allows 13,000 storage. Most of the places that are left and currently searchable will take several days to identify the resources, let alone actually find them. Does anyone know where the brick can be found?

I'm not interested in spending gems to buy it -- saving those for unlocking more people.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several days of scouring the island, I finally found the location of the Brick: It is the bedrock area, which is just west of the mountain on the northwestern part of the map.

[image: Brick location on Tinker Island]